# Conditions for allowing bounded subset for premetric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In [Bounded subset: Only in metric space or also for premetric space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807304/bounded-subset-only-in-metric-space-or-also-for-premetric-space) it was explained that - in general - a premetric space $(X, m)$, where
\begin{align}
x,x'&\in X\\
m(x,x')&\ge0 \\
m(x,x)&=0 \\
m(x,x')&=m(x',x)
\end{align}

cannot be a [Bornological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space). In other words, a subset $X'$ of the underlying set $X$ of the premetric space can only be [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set) if the "premetric" is actually a metric (additionally fulfilling the triangular inequality).

Now I would like to ask if there is a way to have my premetric *not* fulfill the triangular inequality, but still enable bound-ability. What alternative condition could I impose on the premetric, which is more general than the triangular inequality but still allows to talk about bounded subsets of $X$.

Here is my suggestion for the subset $X'\subset X$:

$$
\exists r > 0: r\in\mathbb R : m(x,x') < r, m(x,x'') > 0 \;\forall\; x,x' \in X', x''\in X\setminus X'
$$